# Delete zero rows from a table in R

Tags: r

I had two data frames one with information about `ProductId`, `Price`, `Location` and other data frame with `ProductId` and `Name`. So I merged them together using following command.

```
DF1$Name <- names$Name[match(DF1$ProductId,names$ProductId)];
```

And it worked fine. Then I took a subset of the DF1 based on certain Location like this

```
DF_London = subset(DF1, Location == "London")
```

In `DF1` `Names` had 100 Levels, In `DF_London` it should have 25 Levels and by using `unique` and `length` I can see it. But in `str(DF_London)` it shows 100 Levels of `Names` and when i try to draw table like

```
with(DF_London,table(Names, Price)
```

It shows a table with 100 rows and many of these rows have all zero values because obviously those names don't exist in `DF_London` data frame.

So how can I either fix the number of Level for Names in DF_London or delete the zero rows?

Sorry for not providing the reproducible example.

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at `?droplevels`.

Comment: @RHertel thanks. it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DF_London$Names <- droplevels(DF_London$Names)
```